# MS XML selectNodes method not returning the expected nodes

Tags: xpath, vb6, xml-parsing

Code in VB6(XML File)

My Xml file as follows

```
<book>
    <name>x1</name>
    <price>1<price>
    <name>x2</name>
    <name>x3</name>
    <price>2<price>
</book>
```

Root Node is Book

```
Set nodlist = xmlDoc.selectNodes("/Book/Price")
```

**It Selects 1 Nodes Only, Rest Are ignored**

And I want to get all the nodes named `price`.

Comment: Frankly with the XML sample given there are no elements named `Book` nor any named `Price` as case matters with XML names. In the sample there are elements named `price` as child elements of a root element named `book` so with XPath you need e.g. `/book/price` which should select two element nodes in the sample you have posted. So with the given XML sample the path `/Book/Price` should select an empty node-set and `selectNodes("/Book/Price")` should return an empty node list with length being 0. If you get a different result then you are processing a different XML document.

Comment: @chotai.mit, so, have you tried any of the proposals ?

Comment: @MartinHonnen The `price` nodes are also not closed properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set nodlist = xmlDoc.selectNodes("/Book/Price")
```

**XPath is CAse senSitiVe -- there are no nodes named `Book` or `Price` in the provided XML document. Therefore the above method call must return an empty `XmlNodeList`**.

You want:

```
Set nodlist = xmlDoc.selectNodes("/book/price")
```

Answer (score 1):

**1/** as [JP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190829/jp) figured out in comments of OP, your second `price` node isn't closed correctly.

The `selectNodes()` method is using a XPath selector ([syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp), [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp)), right ?

**2/** as [Dimitre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev) said, XPath is case sensitive, so `/Book/Price` is invalid if your actual elements are `book` and `price`. It should be `/book/price`.

However, if the first `price` node is returned to you, it's most likely that your selector is actually the well lower-cased `/book/price`, and probaby that you problem comes from the second `price` node which is not properly closed.

**3/** Finally, are you sure that `book` is *really* the *root* node of your XML ? Don't you have any `bookstore` parent, or something?

If your selector has the form `/book/price` (with only one slash at first), it is an *absolute* path, then it should select all `price` elements for the selected `book` indeed, but only il the given `book` is *the (only very single)* root node (with no other `book` in your doc obviously, since you cannot have several roots in one document, and no parent at all).

Try this:

- `book/price` should return all `price` nodes for all `book` nodes of the documents
- `price` should return all `price` nodes whatever be them parent(s) node(s) in the whole documents

If you have another root, like `bookstore`, or `library` and want to use an *absolute path*, try:

- `/bookstore/book/price` (or `/library/book/price`, or whatever your actual root node is)

Also, you can try to access *relatively* to your nodes using something like that, depending or where are you located in your XML tree:

- `//book/price`
- `//price`